# help me with new membership

Tags: civimember

Hello everyone I am a new user of civicrm, I wanted to ask you about a problem I am experiencing. When I have to create a new membership starting from an existing contact I get this kind of error "You either do not have all the permissions needed for this page, or the membership types haven't been fully configured." what can I do to fix it? Thanks to anyone who can give me help and advice.

Answer (score 3):

You may not have configured the membership type correctly, make sure the visibility is public.  This is under CiviCRM's **Administer menu » CiviMember » Membership Types**.